How to increase the size of the flowchart in R Quarto?
I am using R Quarto. My code below produces the flowchart that is too small. I need to increase the size of flowchart. How to do that?
---
title: "Untitled"
format: beamer
editor: visual
---
  
  ## Quarto
  
  ```{r}
#| echo: false


library(tidyverse)
library(conflicted)


library(DiagrammeR)


grViz("digraph flowchart {
      # node definitions with substituted label text
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle]        
      tab1 [label = '@@1']
      tab2 [label = '@@2']
      tab3 [label = '@@3']
      tab4 [label = '@@4']
      tab5 [label = '@@5']

      # edge definitions with the node IDs
      tab1 -> tab2;
      tab2 -> tab3;
      tab2 -> tab4 -> tab5
      }

      [1]: 'Questionnaire sent to n=1000 participants'
      [2]: 'Participants came to clinic for evaluation n=700'
      [3]: 'Participants non-eligible for the study n=100'
      [4]: 'Participants eligible for the study n=600'
      [5]: 'Study sample n=600'
      ")



```

DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
